# Adobe Flex / Actionscript - Min Max of Array Collection

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, adobe

I have an ArrayCollection derived from a httpService call where the XML looks like the following:

> ```
> <data>
>     <label>John</label><height>5.5</height>
>     <label>John</label><height>7.2</height>
>     <label>John</label><height>3.2</height>
> </data>
> ```

I know how to use Math.min and Math.max on an array but how would I get the min and max of just the height in this example? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an ArrayCollection?  Or XML?  Is each element of your ArrayCollection a data object?  And does each data object have three labels and three heights?

Comment: I have the data in an ArrayCollection. Each element of my ArrayCollection is a data object. Sorry I wasn't very clear about the strucuture. Data is the parent; there is only one data and each 'record' conists of a label and height. I don't know if that's any clearer.

Comment: @user677325 I'm not understanding, perhaps due to my inexperience w/ XML.  In your sample the 'data' tag has three label children, and three height.  So, given that data structure, you'll end up with an ArrayCollection that has one element?  But, I'm not sure how you'd access it; because which value would data.label return?

Comment: Sorry, it's probably my fault since I'm not too familiar with the nomenclature. In my example there would be three elements. I can view label and height in a two column data grid. I was wondering if it was possible to create a 3 item array for just height from the ArrayCollection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use [the `ArrayCollection`'s `Sort` method](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/05/sorting-an-arraycollection-using-the-sortfield-and-sort-classes/) to sort it by height. Then just take the height values from the first and last records in the `ArrayCollection`.

**Update:**

I'll add shaunhusain's solution since code formatting in comments isn't the best.

```
public var minValue:int = int.MAX_VALUE; 
public var maxValue:int = -1; 

for each (var o:Object in myArrayCollection)
{
  if (o.height > maxValue)
    maxValue = o.height;

  if (o.height < minValue)
    minValue = o.height;
}
```

Comment: Although this isn't the most efficient solution it's certainly simple and achieves the goal, alternatively you could iterate across the list and simply do the two comparisons and conditional assignment and it should be a bit quicker than sorting.  int minValue=-1; int maxValue = int.MAX_VALUE; in the loop iterate across the set from i to length if(minValue<currentValue) minValue = currentValue; if(maxValue>currentValue) maxValue=currentValue;  Also to note if you use a sort you may need to parseFloat if the objects are Strings so it doesn't do alphabetical sorting.

Comment: @shaunhusain, Looping through the `ArrayCollection` manually is more efficient than using a `Sort`? I've never compared the two to see which is better. I've always assumed since `Sort` was a native method it would be optimized or more efficient than a regular `for` loop. Good call on the `parseFloat` though. I assumed height was already typed as a Number.

Comment: I wasn't entirely sure but based on this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm I'm pretty sure I'm right, the case for just looping through the collection n times vs the ideal case for sorting in the same time (most of the time not ideal).  I haven't actually tested that statement but in theory it seemed right.  To be a stickler you could also set o.height to a local variable to reduce dereferencing but honestly I'm not sure how much low level optimizations apply to AS3.  Thanks for writing it out though.

Answer (score 1):

Do you already have data stored in the ArrayCollection?
If so, use the Debugger to see the structure of the collection.
After that it should be as simple as looping through the collection and finding the min and max. If data is like myAC[0]['height'],myAC[1]['height'] etc you can't use Math methods.

Comment: This is the type of approach I would recommend, although I'm uncertain what the data structure is.